What's the intent of the dimming/undimming feature on DV'd answers?
Answers with negative net votes are shown in a dimmed font color, but when you hover the mouse over one it returns to normal color (on computer, haven't tried phone).
What is the intent of both of those features?
I guess the dimming is to draw attention away from a poor answer?  That would be fine.  But the flashing caused by the hover feature as you randomly pass the mouse over it has the opposite effect.  It's jarring and draws all my attention away from the entire thread of the page.  And if undim-on-hover does anything useful, it's lost on me.

To me it just very obviously points out that an answer is incorrect, which is great when going through a list of potential solutions. Undim-on-hover makes the answer more legible once a user decides to focus on it. This seems very intuitive to me. (Its jarringness probably mostly depends on the way the user navigates, whether or not they forget the on-screen position of their cursor as they scroll through a page.)

If the intent is to make the post more legible if you choose to read it, and if most users hover their mouse over it more intentionally and few users do it in passing as I seem to experience .... I guess that's it then?  My experience is worse.

Related to What does a greyed-out answer mean?

"as you randomly pass" What are you doing with your mouse while reading? Randomly moving it? I didn't think I move it much when reading.

@Charlotte This is not a feature request or a bug report. What was the intent behind marking this as [tag:status-declined]?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution A lot of people compulsively move their mouse around or select text as they read things on a computer. I randomly select and highlight text on a page while I read; it's something I've done as long as I can remember... no reason why that I can really give... maybe I just subconsciously feel like my mouse should always be active while I'm on the computer/reading the internet? Just to answer your question :-)

@CPlus [tag:status-bydesign] may be a more appropriate status tag. Then again, isn't this more of a [tag:support] question than a discussion? It should have a kind of definitive answer.

@Glorfindel I do not understand how [tag:status-bydesign] would work either. There is no change being requested. Simply the rationale of an existing feature. By adding [tag:status-declined] to a [tag:support]/[tag:discussion] question, what, are they declining to provide an official answer?

The dimming effect is so that it's immediately obvious (but in a subtle and not obnoxious way) that the answer is significantly downvoted.
The effect on hover (making the answer appear normal) is so that it's easier to read the answer anyway, should you choose to do so. For people with poor vision, this may be the only way they can read the text, so it's an accessibility feature.

If it is intently an accessibility feature, and if research has been done that net-net it achieves a good balance between, then, THREE effects -- 1) dim poor answers 2) make it legible to those who need that without complicating the UI with more buttons , 3) annoy some people like me.  Then THAT's the answer.  And effect #3 is not so bad in that context.

Is there a way to undim (access) the content of such answers on mobiles? More and more traffic comes from mobiles.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Tapping the answer undims the same way a click does. You can also undim with just a keyboard (e.g. with "add comment") but it's extremely unintuitive and could really use a rework.

I don't think it's immediately obvious that the dimming indicates a downvoted answer, but it is immediately obvious that "the site wants to hide this post a bit for some reason", and then the next most apparent piece of information when I go looking for why is indeed the score of the post. At least, that's my perspective on it.

To me, this behaviour is not so much about drawing attention away, as it is to clearly point out that an answer is incorrect, which is great when going through a list of potential solutions.
Undim-on-hover makes the answer more legible once a user actively decides to focus on it.
This seems very intuitive to me.

You suggest modifying user behavior to avoid poorly designed features?  Boo to that.  However, from the other answer, perhaps accessibility is behind this feature and if so perhaps the balance is just right.  I don't need to avoid it, just suck it up.  Or maybe that's what you were cryptically suggesting. :)

@jay613 No, I think it comes natural to most (I've never had a problem with it, and always thought it was a clear design feature), but it's just some additional advice to circumvent something that seems to annoy you :) But I removed it. For clarity's sake.

I was baffled by this at first too, but when I realized its goal I did agree it's a good feature. So I can see @jay613 point of view, and my suggestion would be to make it more clear why the font is different, perhaps tooltip or some ? icon. If I'll bake this enough I'll post a feature request. :)
